# Reading Request.Form Variables from a POST request; Always null/empty on a server

Tags: c#, post, request, request.form

I am experiencing an issue when I am using Postman app to send Test Post request to different urls.

As you can see in the below screenshot, I am trying to send a POST request to the first server, which is my local machine. Once the POST request is handled and I try to read the *params* variable `if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Form["params"]))` the value is *test* and everything is OK.

But if I try the SAME POST request to another server (staging server), when I try to read again the params variable `if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Form["params"]))` it will be null/empty

Any help would be much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: is there a return code different from 200 on client side? is the `POST` method configured as accepted method? what is running on the staging server, an IIS? anything logged?

Comment: Yes an IIS on both. On both servers, the same POST method handler.

Comment: Could it be for some reason that the value of params ends up in Request.Params instead of Request.Forms (Request.Params is the union of form and url parameters). But even if that's true, it would not explain why its behaving differently towards two servers.

Comment: I have tried even with different variable name, instead of params, and the same result :/

Comment: Try `Request.Params["params"]` instead of `Request.Form["params"]` just to be sure. I've no idea what's going wrong but your next steps can be turn on request tracing and have a look at the IIS logs. Is the web.config file different on the two hosts? (I'm thinking request validation, filtering, ...)

Comment: Yes, exact the same web.config files.